# fixed size + variable size delimiters

Tags: tex-core, delimiters

### background

I'm trying to understand how TeX typesets `\left( FOOBAR \right}`

### what I understand so far

1. we render `FOOBAR` , get height/depth of the bounding box
2. then, given the height/depth, we try to figure out ( and }
3. there are a number of fixed size ( and }'s (size1, size2, size3, size4)
4. there are "variable" size (} stated as "top part", "mid part", "bot part", "mid part" (and we repeat the rep-part enough times to make the ( and } tall enough)
5. now, there's a bunch of magical constants required to make all this work

### question

where are these magical constants documented?

(I've looked at Appendix G of TeX book)

Thanks!

Comment: The title of your posting mentions both fixed-size and variable-size delimiters, but the body of the query seems to be concerned solely with the latter type. Please clarify the objective of the posting.

Comment: @mico: the fixed size are easier to typeset (you just inject the glyph), but still there's the question of when -- so for examples, there's atleast 4 different fixed size ('s, and there are various constants which decides which one to pick, this would be in step 3 above

Comment: Open `texdoc tex` and look for [`make_left_right`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9poEM.png).